# Windows 7 update issues

Tags: windows-7, windows, windows-update

I have updated Windows 7 for important updates. I rebooted to finish installing them. Nothing but black screen shows. F8 doesn't seem to work. During this the caps locks indicator flashes on and off as does number lock. I tried to restart. Same result.

Compaq and Windows 7

Comment: Are you saying that you don't even see the BIOS splash screen or similar? The update could knock on Windows for sure, but for it not to see the BIOS and or boot up details etc is suspicious in that maybe something else went wrong at the same time

Answer (score 0):

I have seen this on HP laptops.  Both Caps Lock and Num Lock flash.   Both times happened suddenly and simply failed to start and showed a blank screen.  There are many posts about this on HP forums.

See if you can match the pattern of the 'blinks' to those shown on the table below - this may at least give you a better idea of what the problem is.  Sometimes a through cleaning will resolve a CPU issue as it can be heat related and reseating memory and other modules could help.  Both the ones I have seen recently were system board failures.

```
LEDs blink 1 time CPU Error  CPU not functional 
LEDs blink 2 times BIOS Error BIOS corruption failure 
LEDs blink 3 times Memory Error  Module error not functional 
LEDs blink 4 times Graphics Error  Graphics controller not functional 
LEDs blink 5 times System board Error  General system board failure 
LEDs blink 6 times BIOS Error 2  BIOS authentication failure
```